# Translation Manager Windows not loading - Dropdown keep showing "Loading"

Tags: translation-manager, worldserver

After installing and configuring the Translation Manager on Tridion 2013 New server, I am getting below issue and I have tried looking logs but no logs in "debug" mode also.

[image: Translation Screen]

Seems page is not able to load always saying "Loading...", may be some editor configuration missing, any suggestions!!

Comment: is it happening on all browsers? If you are checking on Chrome, can you also verify on Firefox?

Comment: Checked on IE 11, Chrome (latest), Firefox (latest)...All having same issue

Answer (score 2):

It appears your login to TM or WorlsServer is not working.  There are logs I believe in the TM client folder on the server.

Also, I have had an issue before where WorldServer was setup with https and I needed a hot fix.  However, that was using an older version of the connector and I assume it's better now.

Comment: rob, I verified the TM url is accessible from that machince and also I have configured the logs to appear in tridion_home\logs and also enabled the verbose logging true, but no luck and I am not able to see the error logs.

Comment: I think both you mean TMS rather than TM, which could be confused with Translation Manager. But the issue happens with Translation Jobs themselves. So the Translation Manager extension should be the first suspect, right? Maybe it's something between Pankaj's and Robert's points. Double check the browser console, check other browser's as Pankaj suggests, and maybe log a Ticket. Also check to see if this happens with for just new jobs or existing jobs.